# Angular2 RC5 and Elvis Operator

Tags: forms, angular

We get label texts via a web service (data is stored in cmsText) and we have used in RC4 the following construction with the so called Elvis-Operator:

```
<label 
    for="birthyear" 
    [innerhtml]="( cmsText | async )?.page20YearOfBirth">
</label>
```

I does not work anymore with RC5. What should we change?

p.s. `( cmsText | async )` without Elvis gives the full ouput of data (i.e. the data is here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10639 which was fixed 6 days ago and should be contained in RC.6

Comment: how can I currently bypass (umgehen) this problem, what would help?

Comment: This might work `( cmsText | async ) && ( cmsText | async ).page20YearOfBirth`, otherwise I guess you need to subscribe in code, assign the result to a property and bind to that property.